Disable animation on AutoSuggestBox items change?
When making input changes to AutoSuggestBox, the transition to the new search results has an animation, making the lines jump/bounce. I don't want this effect, instead I want the new search results to be displayed without any animation.
So, how can one disable this animation?
This is how it looks by default with the animations (and how I don't want it)


But It behaves normally for me with this..

The AutoSuggestBox shows a ListView for the suggestions. That animation is actually the ListView's animation. The following code should disable the animation:
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.AutoSuggestBoxControl.Loaded += AutoSuggestBoxControl_Loaded;
}

private void AutoSuggestBoxControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs _)
{
    if (sender is not AutoSuggestBox autoSuggestBox ||
        VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(autoSuggestBox, 0) is not Grid grid ||
        grid.Children.FirstOrDefault(gridChild => gridChild is Popup) is not Popup popup ||
        popup.Child is not Border popupChildBorder ||
        popupChildBorder.Child is not ListView popupListView)
    {
        return;
    }

    popupListView.ItemContainerTransitions = null;
}

UPDATE
If you want to do this in XAML:
<AutoSuggestBox
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Cats}"
    TextChanged="AutoSuggestBoxControl_TextChanged">
    <AutoSuggestBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TransitionCollection/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </AutoSuggestBox.Resources>
</AutoSuggestBox>


first of all, that works, thank you. Do you know if it's possible to change this via XAML or styling instead of via code?
